# object type casting in Python after reloading a module? [for on-the-fly code changes]

Tags: python, object, casting, module, reload

I am running an interactive python session which builds **big** python data-structures (5+ GB) which take a long time to load, and so I want to exploit **Python on-the-fly code change** abilities at its maximum (though sometimes, **without having to plan too much for that**).

My current problem is the following: I have an old instance of a class that I have later modified the code and reloaded the module -- I would like the old instance to be able to use the new function definitions. How do I do that without just manually copying all the information from the old instance to a new fresh instance?

Here is what I have tried. Suppose I have the module `M.py`:

```
class A():
    def f(self):
        print "old class"
```

Here is an interactive session:

```
import M
old_a = M.a()

# [suppose now I change the definition of M.A.f in the source file]

reload(M)
# I attempt to use the new class definition with the old instance:
M.A.f(old_a)
```

at which point I get the following type error from Python:

```
TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with A instance as first argument (got A instance instead)
```

Python is obviously not happy to receive an old instance of A even though they are basically functionally equivalent types (in my code) -- is there any way I could 'type cast' it to the new instance type so that Python wouldn't complain? Something morally like: `M.A.f( (M.A) old_a )` ?

Comment: The problem you got is you try to call a object method on a class. For what you want the solution is to get module functions, because methodes are associated to objects so the old object will stay with old method when you reload the module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no casting in Python but you *can* change the class of an existing object: It is perfectly legal and does the job:

```
old_a.__class__=M.A
old_a.f()
```

As long as you haven't changed the relation between class methods and instance variables, changed what `__init__` does or something like that this is perfectly fine.

EDIT: As `jsbueno` points out: The `__init__` or `__new__` methods are *not* called at the point of changing `__class__`. Further, the new `__del__` *will* be called at destruction.

Comment: This is clearly the exact answer for the what is being asked.  Just remembering that the `__init__` and `__new__` methods are not run when  `__class__` is assigned like this (though `__init__` could be manually called from the prompt if needed). Also, it should be mentioned, since it is in the question wording, that there is no casting in Python.

Comment: So given the above comments, could we say that the following would effectively fake type casting in Python: `old_class = old_a.__class__`, `old_a.__class__ = M.A`, `M.A.f(old_a) # function which needed type casting` and `old_a.__class__ = old_class` ?

Comment: @SimonLacoste-Julien I would say no. Type casting (as in C++) for example is completely different. It can for example generate new objects of completely distinct types. For example imagine a complicated object that has a casting operator to `const char *` with some text representation of the contents. So cast is in that sense more like str(someObject).

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot cast, you need to revise your code so that these mysterious "on-the-fly code changes" can work.

Step 1.  Separate Algorithm from Data.  Write a very simple (and very unlikely to change) class for the raw Data.  Often a list of named tuples is all you'll ever need for this.

Step 2.  Create algorithms which work on the data objects by "wrapping" them instead of "updating" them.

Like this.

```
def some_complex_algo( list_of_named_tuples ):
    for item in list_of_named_tuples:
        # some calculation
        yield NewTuple( result1, result2, ..., item )
```

Now you can attempt your processing:

```
result = list( some_complex_algo( source_data ) )
```

If you don't like the result, you only need to redefine your `some_complex_algo` and rerun it.  The `source_data` is untouched.  Indeed, it can be immutable.

Comment: Thanks for the design suggestions. The main issue though is that this requires some code planning. The main point of my question is that I want to be able to modify things *even if* I didn't plan for the changes at the beginning -- this is the point of using a rapid prototyping language like Python IMHO...

Comment: This requires **no** code planning.  Merely separate data from algorithm.  That is all.

Comment: A "rapid prototyping language" is not an excuse to avoid all thinking, BTW.  Coding more-or-less randomly while working with a 5GB file is not really a good idea.  However.  With **no** planning, you can write code that works with immutable data, avoiding anything like casting.

Comment: To give a better idea of the context, I am not reading a 5 GB file but rather reading a few 200 MB files which yield 5 GB+ of constructed data-structure. The whole point of the big data-structure is to make the runtime execution of some algorithms much more efficient (I am basically aligning the knowledge base IMDb with Wikipedia -- that's trying to match millions of entities, for which you can obviously not just look at all pairs). I doubt I could implement all the above efficiently with only immutable data.

Comment: @SimonLacoste-Julien: All of the functional programming language folks will tell you that you most certainly *can* do all of this with immutable objects in a mutable collection.  They do it all the time.  Mutable objects aren't **essential**.  "to make the runtime execution of some algorithms much more efficient" you have to have the right data structure and the right algorithm.  Mutability has little to do with this.  Appropriate use of Mappings and Sets is more important than mutability.