# Save A Reloaded Python Module For Testing Purposes

Tags: python, reload, python-2.6, python-2.x, python-unittest

I have a Python module that I am testing, and because of the way that the module works (it does some initialization upon import) have been reloading the module during each `unittest` that is testing the initialization. The `reload` is done in the `setUp` method, so all tests are actually reloading the module, which is fine.

This all works great if I am only running tests in that file during any given Python session because I never required a reference to the previous instance of the module. But when I use Pydev or `unittest`'s `discover` I get errors as seen [here](http://thingspython.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/another-super-wrinkle-raising-typeerror/) because other tests which import this module have lost their reference to objects in the module since they were imported before all of the reloading business in my tests.

There are similar questions around SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165855/576333), but those all deal with updating objects after reloads have occurred. What I would like to do is save the state of the module after the initial import, run my tests that do all of the reloading, and then in the test `tearDown` to put the initial reference to the module back so that tests that run downstream that use the module still have the correct reference. Note that I am not making any changes to the module, I am only reloading it to test some initialization pieces that it does.

There are also some solutions that include hooks in the module code which I am not interested in. I don't want to ask developers to push things into the codebase just so tests can run. I am using Python 2.6 and `unittest`. I see that some projects exist like [process-isolation](https://github.com/alexflint/process-isolation), and while I am not sure if that does entirely what I am asking for, it does not work for Python 2.6 and I don't want to add new packages to our stack if possible. Stub code follows:

```
import mypackage.mymodule
saved_module = mypackage.mymodule

class SomeTestThatReloads(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        reload(mypackage.mymodule)

    def tearDown(self):
        # What to do here with saved_module?

    def test_initialization(self):
        # testing scenario code
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do that. If your module's initialization has side effects (and by the looks of it it does -- hooks, etc.), there is no automated way to undo them, short of entirely restarting the Python process.

Similarly, if anything in your code imports something from your module rather than the module itself (e.g. `from my_package.my_module import some_object` instead of `import my_package.my_module`), reloading the module won't do anything to the imported objects (`some_object` will refer to whatever `my_package.my_module.some_object` referred to when the `import` statement was executed, regardless of what you reload and what's on the disk).

The problem this all comes down to is that Python's module system works by executing the modules (which is full of side effects, the definition of classes/functions/variables being only one of many) and then exposing the top-level variables they created, and the Python VM itself treats modules as one big chunk of global state with no isolation.

Therefore, the general solution to your problem is to restart a new Python process after each test (which sucks :( ).

If your modules' initialization side effects are limited, you can try running your tests with Nose instead of Unittest (the tests are compatible, you don't have to rewrite anything), whose Isolate plugin attempts to do what you want: http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/isolate.html

But it's not guaranteed to work in the general case, because of what I said above.